# What you mean by SCORM tracking

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

am new to this SCORM  (Shareable Content Object Reference Model) and i have gone through some tutorials about that.  Can anyone please tell me what exactly mean by **SCORM tracking** or any good link to the tutorials for the same .

Also what is mean by SCORM tracing ??
What is the difference between SCROM tracing and tracking ??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SCORM tracking is the part of the standard describing what information is required to describe the interaction the learner has had with a course content.  This information is used to *track* a leaner's progression.

For example it defines The leaner's Score, Success or Failure status, Completion status and the Time Spent on the content.

You can download the [specification (the RTE document applies to the Tracking part)](http://www.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/2004%204th%20Edition/Documentation.aspx)

I'm afraid I don't have any links to particular Tutorials other than those you might find by googling

Comment: Thanks Tom. Can you please provide me some good links for the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Tom pretty much answered the question about tracking, but the best reference that I have found is *e-Learning Standards* by Fallon and Brown.